# Angular directive new scope rule

Tags: angularjs

The Angular directive documentation says: "If set to true, then a new scope will be created for this directive. If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created. The new scope rule does not apply for the root of the template since the root of the template always gets a new scope."

My question is the last sentence. I assume that "template" refers to the directive's template, but on testing a simple directive whether it has or doesn't have a template, no new scope is created without setting "scope: true". Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can anybody add clarity to this statement in doc?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the "root of the template" there means the root element which matches ngController directive. In the example below, the first and second myCustomer directives belong to the same "root template", but the third one is different.

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">        
    <my-customer></my-customer>       

    <div>
        <my-customer></my-customer>       
    </div>      
</div>

<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <my-customer></my-customer>       
</div>
```